# Oracle SQL Query to find e-mail addresses starting with numbers

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
Select * from Table_name where Column_name like '1%@%'
```

returns me all email addresses starting with '1'.What I want is to get mail IDs that has username  with all and any numbers. Like '23456@domain.com' or '787654398@domain.com'.Is there any  operator like `%` that refers not just any characters but numbers only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(email, '^[0-9]+@');
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can you explain why is the '+' there.

Comment: Well `[0-9]+` means one or more numbers.